# How to separate package name by regex in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm writing a script function to separate package tar ball name listing into package name version.

```
xorg-fonts-misc-1.0b-1
Xorg-font-bitstream-75dpi-1.0.0-2.i386
Xorg-font-bitstream-100dpi-1.2a-2.arm
Other-Third-Party-1.2.2-1-any
```

I'm using the following script to separate name and version.

```
split_pkgname_pipe() {  # split x-x-1.3-1.x -> x-x 1.3-1.x
  [ $opt_v != 0 ] && echo "dbg:split_pkgname_pipe $*" >&2
  awk '{
    f=$0
    sub(/\-[0-9].*$/,"")
    n=$1
    v=substr(f, length(n)+2)
    print n, v
  }'
}
```

The problem of my code will cause `Xorg-font-bitstream-75dpi-1.0.0` separate as `Xorg-font-bitstream` and `75dpi-1.0.0`. But I want `Xorg-font-bitstream-75dpi` and `-1.0.0`

[SOLVED]

```
split_pkgname_pipe() {  # split x-x-1.3-1.x -> x-x 1.3-1.x
  [ $opt_v != 0 ] && echo "dbg:split_pkgname_pipe $*" >&2
  local line namever name ver rel
  while read line ; do
    namever="${line%-*}"
    rel="${line##*-}"
    if [ `expr match $rel '[0-9]'` = 0 ] ; then # rel is 'i386/any'...
      name="${namever%-*}"
      ver="${namever##*-}"
      namever="$name"
      rel="$ver-$rel"
    fi
    name="${namever%-*}"
    ver="${namever##*-}"
    echo "$name $ver-$rel"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ package="Xorg-font-bitstream-75dpi-1.0.0"
$ echo "${package%-*}"
Xorg-font-bitstream-75dpi
$ echo "${package##*-}"
1.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks you give me hint.  For the package name it is more complex, so I post my solution in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sed -re '/^(.*?)((\d[a-z]?\.)+.*)$/\1\t\2/gmi' file.txt
```